# DDP issue, logout after refresh

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am connecting two applications sharing 1 login. Application 1 is the login page only and the application 2 is the a chat box. Everything is sync, the chat app can login using the application 1's registered user. However, when I refresh the chat app, the user logs out automatically. The loginToken is not there any more.

I've been trying to stop the auto logout using:

```
Accounts.config ({loginExpirationInDays: null})
```

LocalSession, Browser Cookies but nothing seem to work. Is there a way the app can recall the login token used after refreshing? Please help thank you so much.